# Como fazer uma pagina HTML sobrepor a outra

Tags: html

Olá,
Gostaria de sabe se teria como fazer com que uma pagina sobreponha (*"invada"*) a outra, tipo este modelo aqui:

[image: Divisória entre a pagina 1/2]

Comment: Normalmente isso é uma página só, com seções diferentes. Você pode até simular isso carregando pedaços com JS, ou usando _includes_, quem sabe até `iframe`, mas no fim vira tudo uma página só (e é fundamental entender como uma coisa só para poder projetar a folha de estilos responsável pela transição).

Answer (score 2):

Isso é apenas uma página, o que acontece é que a parte branca que é uma `<div>` está sobre outra `<div>`, isso é feito em CSS com a função `z-index`, exemplo:

**HTML**

```
<div id="imagem"></div>
<div id="bg_branco"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#imagem {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     top: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     position: absolute;
     background-image: url(http://www.onordeste.com/administrador/personalidades/imagemPersonalidade/34d6911fdfdc4097a974a4b612313f70923.JPG);
     z-index: 1;
}

#bg_branco {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50%;
     top: 70%;
     left: 0px;
     background-color: #FFF;
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Na verdade esse efeito foi feito usando provavelmente um `::before` por cima do background.

No elemento `::before` vc pode usar o `transform:skewY()` para ter esse efeito.

**Exemplo simples** *(coloquei uma pequena transparencia para vc ver que a imagem continua por baixo do ::before. Também coloquei uma div após a imagem pra vc ver como fica em um layout padrão)*

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.bgimg {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(http://fillmurray.com/500/500) no-repeat ;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bgimg::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 135px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -67px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: skewY(4deg);
    clear: both;
}
.corpo {
    background-color: lightgray;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimg"></div>
    <div class="corpo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nemo, quaerat.</div>
```